# Can I mark an issue as "false-positive" from a sonarqube plugin?

Tags: sonarqube

Just as I can do auto-assignment for issues from my sonarqube plugin using the API of IssueHandler and Issue.Context.assign(User), can I mark an issue as false-positive from my plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is currently possible. But:

- With all the changes currently being done for the next 5.2 version, this won't be possible any more.
- So if you have a use case that you think is valid, please feel free to come and discuss this on the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube)!

Comment: Sure will do and will keep that in mind.  In the mean time could you point me to the relevant API for the same in your post.